# How to specify destination as parent directory

Tags: gruntjs

I have a coffee file which I am planning put in the coffee directory, so the directory structure is going to be

public/javascripts/coffee/*.coffee

I want the javascript to be compile and put into public/javascripts/ . Since this is going to be across other folders as well I want this to be generic. meaning I am planning to have a coffee folder in each and plan to place the javascript in the parent folder. how could this be achieved. This is current config I have, which just creates the js in the same folder as the coffee file.

```
coffee:
    dev:                
        options:
            bare: true
            join: true
            sourceMap: true
        expand: true
        cwd: '.'
        src : ['**/*.coffee','!node_modules/**/*.coffee','!GruntFile.coffee']
        dest: 'src/../'
        ext: '.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a rename option available which takes a function module(I have mine in coffeescript)

```
coffee:
    dev:                
        options:
            bare: true
            join: true
            sourceMap: true
        expand: true                
        src : ['**/*.coffee','!node_modules/**/*.coffee','!GruntFile.coffee']
        ext: '.js'
        rename: (src,dest)->
            arr = dest.split 'coffee/'
            return arr.join('')
```